# mailman recover list from file

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mailman, mailing-list

can i recover users of a list from broken harddisk. i can see /var/lib/mailman/lists folder and files inside it. there are folders for each list and pck files inside them.

also lots of db files are in mailman folder.

how can i see lists of users from this file?

thx in advance..

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately:

```
bin/list_members
```

will only work if the lists are in Mailman's list directory. If they're just in some random location on a disk, you can use the following tool from Mailman's directory:

```
bin/dumpdb /path/to/file
```

It'll dump out the contents of 'pickle' files as readable text. From there you can see the users in the list.

Comment: Just tested this on my mailman setup, and it works.

Answer (score 0):

In your mailman directory:

```
bin/list_members [listname]
```